# JLabel disappears when using html

Tags: java, html, swing, user-interface

I have a JLabel that is going to have a lot of text in it so I need to add new lines to it. I found out that in order to do this you need to use html in your JLabel and `<br>` for a new line. Well, as soon as I add HTML to my JLabel it disappears!!

Here is a picture of the JLabel with the following code:

```
instructionLabel = new JLabel("lol");
instructionLabel.setBounds(25,10,500,100);
add(instructionLabel);
```

http://prntscr.com/9p1cme

Now, when I change the code, as soon as I add html, it disappears:

```
instructionLabel = new JLabel("<html>lol</html>");
instructionLabel.setBounds(25,10,500,100);
add(instructionLabel);
```

http://prntscr.com/9p1d4u

The program gives no errors & I am willing to provide more code if necessary.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: @madprogrammer Could that be a reason this is happening? Seems like a separate issue. None of the layouts look at all appealing to the type of program I am making. I dont want my components just stacked on top of each other, or in a grid, etc

Comment: Well, since I have no context over how you want the layout to work, then I can can't say, but since you've made NO effort to calculate the expected requirements of the label, it is a very good bet

Comment: @madProgrammer what do you mean calculate the expected requirements of the label? I just want it to show multiple lines of text. Anywho, here is what my program looks like http://prntscr.com/9p1hcn and here you can find the source code: https://github.com/charlieSplittstoser/HighLow

Comment: Having tried your code with a `null` layout, to works fine for me.  I would how ever, highly recommend using a layout manager, as the Swing API has been written around them, so you will constantly be trying to reinvent the wheel to make things work

Comment: But how do you know how much space the `JLabel` would likely use?

Comment: @madprogrammer I don't know how much space it will use but I set it at 100px tall for now just because it shouldn't take more than that. But either way, even with just one word in the JLabel, the html still makes it disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

[image: HtmlLabel]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class LabelExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LabelExample();
    }

    public LabelExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            add(new JLabel("Look ma, no html"));
            add(new JLabel("<html>Look ma, html</html>"));
        }

    }

}
```

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Based on this requirement...

[image: Requirement]

I did a simple `GridBagLayout` and produced this...

[image: Score]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class LabelExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LabelExample();
    }

    public LabelExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JLabel points = new JLabel("<html><b>Points: 0</b></html>");
            JLabel highscore = new JLabel("<html><b>Highscore: 0</b></html>");
            JLabel score = new JLabel("97");
            score.setFont(score.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 96));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            add(points, gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            add(highscore, gbc);

            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.ipadx = 50;
            gbc.ipady = 50;
            score.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(score, gbc);

            JButton high = new JButton("High");
            JButton low = new JButton("Low");

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(high, gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            add(low, gbc);
        }


    }

}
```

This is just a rough start to provide a basic example of the idea

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't really want to overhaul my entire layout just to see if it makes some html work. It is duly noted for future reference though, thanks. I'm just starting out and not familiar with layouts yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can try below code to solve your problem. 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Tutorial extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Tutorial();
    }

    public Tutorial() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel instructionLabel = new JLabel("<html><p>lol <br> Working</p></html>");
        instructionLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        instructionLabel.setBounds(25,10,500,100);
        getContentPane().add(instructionLabel);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```